# Passing Data from acitvity to fragment android studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

--This is my Fragment :--

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_save, container, false);


    savedAlamat = view.findViewById(R.id.saved_alamat);
    savedContac = view.findViewById(R.id.saved_kontak);
    savedName = view.findViewById(R.id.saved_nama);


    String malamat = getArguments().getString("mAlamat");
    String mcontac = getArguments().getString("mContac");
    String mname = getArguments().getString("mname");

    savedAlamat.setText(malamat);
    savedContac.setText(mcontac);
    savedName.setText(mname);


    return view;
}
```

//and This is main acivity that constarin framelayout :

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_save, container, false);


    savedAlamat = view.findViewById(R.id.saved_alamat);
    savedContac = view.findViewById(R.id.saved_kontak);
    savedName = view.findViewById(R.id.saved_nama);


    String malamat = getArguments().getString("mAlamat");
    String mcontac = getArguments().getString("mContac");
    String mname = getArguments().getString("mname");

    savedAlamat.setText(malamat);
    savedContac.setText(mcontac);
    savedName.setText(mname);


    return view;
}
```

--I don't understand why I keep get NotNULLobject, i want to make a passing data between that activity and fragment.

Comment: Hi. Note that you can embed images directly into your post - instead of pasting links to images.

Comment: @dwjohnston sorry , what exactly did u mean, i think i dont passing an image there

Comment: @AndreasCapone Hi and welcome to SO :-) I'd go a step further and ask you to post your code in text form, it will be way easier for anyone willing to help.

Comment: @RomainValeri edited :D

Answer (score 1):

In Activity, write this code

```
  Bundle bundle = new Bundle(); 
  bundle.putString("mAlamat", "Data to send"); // set Fragmentclass Arguments 
  Fragmentclass fragobj = new Fragmentclass(); 
  fragobj.setArguments(bundle);
```

> In Fragment class, receive data like this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    String strtext = getArguments().getString("mAlamat");    
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
}
```

[Courtesy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739909/send-data-from-activity-to-fragment-in-android)